# How to download ordinary (non-ggplot) plots & text to a file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to download to files: one non-ggplot2 plot & another a string/vector, but it doesn't save both the files in the directory.

**Symptom:**
1) When I click the plotdownload button in UI, it opens a pdf with a temp filename,"rstudio-xxx.pdf" displaying the desired plot, but it doesn't save the file automatically. 
2) When I click the datadownload button in UI, it lets me browse the local folders with the right filename as default, but after clicking save button, it doesn't really save the file in the selected directory

***Code***

```
**ui.R**

 wellPanel(
     downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download Plot'),
     downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download File'),
     br()
 )


**server.R**

plotInput <- function() {
    if(input$save == 0)
        return()

    plotdata() ** function call to plot **
}
output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste0("test.pdf") },
    content = function(file) {
        pdf(file,width=12,height=6)
        print(plotInput())
        dev.off()
    })        

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "test.txt") },
    content = function(file){
        write.table(c(1:10),file)
    }
)
```

....

***End of code***

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Appreciate your help!

thanks